# MongoDB: Nested values vs separate collections for search performance - DB schema design

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema

Suppose I have a MongoDB where I have separate `texts` which consist of `statements`.

I need to be able to search for the `texts`, which have certain keywords in `statements` (also multiple texts that have an occurrence of a search term).

I also need to be able to find all the `statements` in all the texts added by a particular user, which contain a particular search phrase.

My question: do I need to create a separate collection for `statements` or can I simply add them as nested into the `texts` collection?

So, **option 1 (separate collections):**

Texts collection

```json
text: {
    name: 'nabokov',
    id: '1'
}
```

Statements collection:

```json
statement: {
    text_id: '1',
    id: '24',
    text: 'He opened the window and saw the sky`
}
```

**Option 2 (nested):**

```json
text: {
    name: 'nabokov',
    id: '1'
    statements: [
        id: '24',
        text: 'He opened the window and saw the sky`
    ]
}
```

Which MongoDB storage schema is better if I want to retrieve statements separately based on keyword search and retain the contextual data (e.g. which text they belong to etc.)

How would this affect the write / read speed for larger DBs (e.g. > 100 Gb).

My texts would be limited to 16 Mb.

Comment: how big(how many members) is expected to be the statements array in option2? this is important factor to decide. big documents => slower updates(load in memory) => problem if you update them often

Comment: @Takis_ there could be tens of thousands of statements there. Is i faster you think to write them into a separate collection rather than inside a document?

Comment: i think so, but its better to ask more experienced people also, if you want [ask here also](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/) giving them all information possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MongoDB document schema design w.r.t. performance, there are several factors that could be helpful to take into consideration:

1. What are the cardinalities of the relationships between collections?
2. What is the expected number/size of documents in a collection?
3. What are the most frequently used queries?
4. how often are documents getting updated?

For your scenario, we actually need more context / details from you to work out a more sensible "answer". But here are some common scenarios that I have personally come into before and it might be useful for you as a reference.

1. `text` as a root document that is not frequently updated; Most of the queries are based on the `statement` collection as a child collection.

In this case, it could be a good idea to denormalize the `text` document and replicating the field `name` into corresponding `statement` document.
e.g.

```
statement: {
    text_id: '1',
    text_name: 'nabokov',
    id: '24',
    text: 'He opened the window and saw the sky`
}
```

In this way, you gain performance boost by avoiding a `$lookup` to the `text` collection, while only incurring a small cost of maintaining the new `text_name` column. The cost is small since the `text` document is not going to be updated frequently anyway.

2. a `text` document will be associated with small number of `statements` objects/documents only.

In this case, it could be a good idea to go for your option 1 (i.e. keep the statements in an array of `text` document). The advantage is you can compose rather simple queries and avoid the cost in maintaining another collection of `statement`.

Here is a [very good document](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3) to read more about MongoDB schema design.